# Dart Is there a way to get HTTPS content?

Tags: flutter, dart

I really need help. I try to get the rss feed from this url:
- https://www.france24.com/fr/rss?time=1573661731673
But I don't know how to do it when using a https url, I tried to use the HTTP dart library. Here is my code:

````
    import 'package:html/parser.dart';
    import 'package:html/dom.dart';
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'package:http/http.dart';

class Parser {

  final String urlSite = "http://www.france24.com/fr/actualites/rss";


  Future chargerRSS() async{
    final reponse = await get(urlSite);
    if(reponse.statusCode == 200){
      final feed = RssFeed.parse(reponse.body);
      print("$feed at parser");
    }
    else{
      print("Erreur: ${reponse.statusCode}");
    }
  }

}```
````

Comment: What is the issue you are facing with your current attempt?